# Get list properties of object React Native

Tags: arrays, json, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I don't want to get the ID of each object in my array.
**I have this array**

```
[
  {
    "-ML8Lx8jOSv64Ecat611": {
      "category": "Automotive Parts & Accessories",
      "description": "I will be there at least but I don't know if I can help in any way I can",
      "item": "Apple Watch",
      "price": "429,99",
      "timestamp": "2020-11-02T21:28:11+07:00",
      "viewCount": 0
    }
  }
]
```

**What I expected to get is**

```
[
  {
      "category": "Automotive Parts & Accessories",
      "description": "I will be there at least but I don't know if I can help in any way I can",
      "item": "Apple Watch",
      "price": "429,99",
      "timestamp": "2020-11-02T21:28:11+07:00",
      "viewCount": 0
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the object you want in the output is nested, you'll need to loop over two levels in your JSON:

```js
let input = [
  {
    "-ML8Lx8jOSv64Ecat611": {
      "category": "Automotive Parts & Accessories",
      "description": "I will be there at least but I don't know if I can help in any way I can",
      "item": "Apple Watch",
      "price": "429,99",
      "timestamp": "2020-11-02T21:28:11+07:00",
      "viewCount": 0
    }
  }
];

let result = []
input.forEach(obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    result.push(obj[key]);
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[
  {
    "-ML8Lx8jOSv64Ecat611": {
      "category": "Automotive Parts & Accessories",
      "description": "I will be there at least but I don't know if I can help in any way I can",
      "item": "Apple Watch",
      "price": "429,99",
      "timestamp": "2020-11-02T21:28:11+07:00",
      "viewCount": 0
    }
  }
]
```

In the above example you are using multiple objects in an object which requires unique key. You can simply use multiple objects in array just like this:

```
[
    {
      "category": "Automotive Parts & Accessories",
      "description": "I will be there at least but I don't know if I can help in any way I can",
      "item": "Apple Watch",
      "price": "429,99",
      "timestamp": "2020-11-02T21:28:11+07:00",
      "viewCount": 0
    },
    {
      "category": "Automotive Parts & Accessories",
      "description": "I will be there at least but I don't know if I can help in any way I can",
      "item": "Apple Watch",
      "price": "429,99",
      "timestamp": "2020-11-02T21:28:11+07:00",
      "viewCount": 0
    },
    .....
]
```

Now you can access each object by the array index. Hope my answer helps you.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean like that it means i need some way to cut the ID of object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var data = [
  {
    "-ML8Lx8jOSv64Ecat611": {
      "category": "Automotive Parts & Accessories",
      "description": "I will be there at least but I don't know if I can help in any way I can",
      "item": "Apple Watch",
      "price": "429,99",
      "timestamp": "2020-11-02T21:28:11+07:00",
      "viewCount": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "-NOa8Lx8jOSv64Ecat611": {
      "category": "Automotive Parts & Accessories",
      "description": "I will be there at least but I don't know if I can help in any way I can",
      "item": "Apple Watch",
      "price": "429,99",
      "timestamp": "2020-11-02T21:28:11+07:00",
      "viewCount": 0
    }
  }
]

console.log(data.map((item) => Object.values(item)[0]))
```